# data coming from Serial port but database not updating

Tags: c#, database, serial-port

data is receiving from a `serial port` but not comparing with declare string and I want to update the `unit_consumed` field in record table in database. while loop is also working. i want to know how serial data compares with string and then update the database field.

```
  int unit = 0;
        string s = "unit_consumed";
        SerialPort myport = new SerialPort();
        myport.BaudRate = 9600;
        myport.PortName = "COM4";
        myport.Open();
        while(true)
        {
            string data_rx = myport.ReadLine();
            File.AppendAllText("test_file.txt", data_rx + "\n");
            unit = unit + 1;
            if (string.Equals(data_rx,s))
            {
                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=MIAN\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=arduino;Integrated Security=True");
                con.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into record(unit_consumed) values(@unit_consumed) ", con);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@unit_consumed", unit);
                con.Close();
            }
            Console.WriteLine(data_rx);
```

Comment: Have you verified that this `string.Equals(data_rx,s)` is true?

Comment: string.equals(data_rx,s) also not working. data is also writing in text file and it contains unit_consumed line  but i don't know why strings.equals not working.

Comment: It should work try changing "if (string.Equals(data_rx,s))" to "if (data_rx.ToLower().Contains(s))" to make sure nothing is missing

Answer (score 0):

Your not executing your query.

Try:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=MIAN\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=arduino;Integrated Security=True");
con.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into record(unit_consumed) values(@unit_consumed) ", con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@unit_consumed", unit);

// ********** need to execute 
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

con.Close();
```